# Clear canvas drawing: Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

Once the drawing is done on canvas as follows:

```
@Composable
fun DrawFigures(count: Int){
    val radius = 200f
    val animateFloat = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    if(count == 1)
        LaunchedEffect(animateFloat) {
            animateFloat.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 3000, easing = LinearEasing))
        }

   Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
       drawArc(
           color = Color.Black,
           startAngle = 0f,
           sweepAngle = 360f * animateFloat.value,
           useCenter = false,
           topLeft = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height / 4),
           size = Size(radius * 2 ,
               radius * 2),
           style = Stroke(2.0f))

    //Other drawings
    drawLine(..)
    drawLine(..)
   }
}
```

This animates circle drawing. But after recomposition no matter what the count value is, the circle is always shown. How can we clear canvas or is there any other way we can achieve this animation based on the value of count?

**Edit**: There are other drawings which need to be drawn and this composable is called and recompositions are done based on the count value. It is a game and when user clicks to play again, count value will be equal to zero.

Comment: I am not sure about the question. If you don't want the canvas, just don't call the DrawFigures composable.

Comment: Please check the edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the state hoisting technique if you want to clear the Canvas element.

```
@Composable
fun DrawFigures(count: Int){
    val radius = 200f
    val animateFloat = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    ...
    if(animateFloat.isRunning){ // The Canvas will disappear if the Animator is completed. Also, it won't appear when the Animator hasn't started yet
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The result here:

[image: Result image]

See more: [State in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-state#5)